# Generic function signatures

Tags: f#

I'm endeavouring to port a C# app to F# and I have this interface:

```
public interface ISerializer
{
    string ContentType { get; }
    string Serialize(object value);
    T Deserialize<T>(string value);
}
```

So I'd like to define a type like this:

```
type Serializer = {ContentType: string; Serialize: Object -> string; Deserialize<'T>: string -> 'T}
```

But I can't. What's the functional way here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the same interface in F# like this:

```
type ISerializer =
    abstract ContentType : string
    abstract Serialize : obj -> string
    abstract Deserialize<'a> : string -> 'a
```

There's no way to get the same "internal" polymorphism with a natural functional datatype such as a record, so you have to use the OO constructs.

If you really wanted to use a record, you could define a single wrapper for `Deserialize` and put that inside a record:

```
type IDeserializer =
    abstract Deserialize<'a> : string -> 'a

type Serializer =
    {
        ContentType : string
        Serialize : obj -> string
        Deserializer : IDeserializer
    }
```

but I don't think it's really worthwhile.